# Should I use INT, CHAR or VARCHAR for Social Security Number?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing the database for a new project, and I am not sure if I should use INT, CHAR or VARCHAR for the Social Security Number of the employees. In my country the SSN is composed of 11 digits.

Notice that I'll be using an ID column as primary key on this table, so the SSN won't be used as key.

**INT considerations**: it won't be possible to store text incorrectly on the column, which is good, but I won't be able to make sure the inserted value has the right number of digits.

**CHAR considerations**: I can make sure entries have the right number of digits, but I can't be sure those will be numbers, and the length of the SSN might increase in the future.

**VARCHAR considerations**: doesn't have any of the benefits of the other two, but is the most flexible one and won't suffer if the length changes, for example.

Is there a standard data type for SSN? What do you guys use?

Comment: Since not everyone is from the USA you should add the format of the SSN.

Comment: So only numbers from 0-9?

Comment: @juergend Yep only numbers 0-9, 11 digits.

Comment: You might want to consider encrypting social security numbers first, in which case either char or binary will be the most logical.

Comment: @Jack good point. Thanks.

Comment: So there's plenty of ways in math to verify number of digits, ranging from computationally expensive (floor(log10(n)+1) = 11) to relatively cheap ones (sign(n-1E10)+sign(n-1E11) = 0), but I must reiterate @Ja͢ck's comment about encryption. Do the validation client-side, encrypt, send, and store encrypted.

Comment: Btw, CHAR(N) and VARCHAR(N) have the same issues when you need to resize; the latter just has the advantage of smaller rows.

Comment: Are you likely to + - x or ÷ SSNs?

Comment: @juergend . . . SSNs in the US have 9 digits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although the SSN is only digits, it doesn't represent a single number. You won't ever be doing any numeric calculations on the whole SSN, so there is really not much point in storing it as a number.

Storing it as a number would use a little less space, but not much, as you would need a `bigint` (8 bytes) to hold an 11 digit number. Using a `varchar` would use 11 bytes for the characters and another byte for the length, so the difference isn't enough to motivate storing it as a number.

Regarding validating the length and content of the SSN, that's really the job of the user interface. The database should not allow anything that hurts the integrity of the data, but an invalid SSN isn't harmful in that way.

I would use a `varchar`, as it offers the flexibility that you mention.

Comment: It would take 13 bytes for most entries as a `varchar`, per MS's definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). An extra 61% growth in database size might impact decisions, depending on use. Just food for thought.

Comment: @JaazCole: That is for SQL Server, not MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Guffa. I'll go with varchar.

Comment: if you do a lot of lookup and join tables based on SSN, strings/varchar's arent really helpful.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: That's true, but I would avoid using it as a key anyway to keep from joining on it. Generally I use autoincrement keys on tables even if they have some unique field combination that could possibly be used as key, so that I don't have to consider if they make an efficient enough key or if they are consistent over time.

Comment: Also note that some countries allow people to get a new SSN - ofcause this could be simulated by migrating the persons data into a new record.

Comment: Also notice that some countries allows people to get a new SSN over time, eg. if their identity has been stolen/hacked. This could be handled by migrating the personalinformation to a new account ofcause, but if you want to be able to handle multiple countries with the same system, then I would recommend a foreign key ID instead of the SSN and then you can implement and change the length/strucuture of the SSN as you please.

Comment: Why bigint?  Why 11 digits?  It's 9 digits, plus 2 hyphens (which you can't represent in a numeric anyway).  Int - 4-bytes, 9 characters (or digits).

Comment: “as you would need a bigint (8 bytes) to hold an 11 digit number”—Depends on the format.  If, say, the particular national identifier format contains a birth date, then the format won’t be in the range 0–99,999,999,999.  But then you need two functions to convert to and from the integer representation.

Comment: @AdamPlocher: Why 11 digits? Because it was specifically stated in the question.

Comment: @Guildenstern: A 32 bit integer can only hold 9 full digits, so you need a 64 bit integer.

Comment: @Guffa Again the string might not use the whole range so you can convert the string to an integer and store that instead (and convert to the nine-digit string on read).  I already mentioned the birth date substring example.  Also, one or more of the digits might be checksum numbers.  Again, depends on the particular string (OP: “in my country”, the country not being stated).

Comment: @Guildenstern: All that is just speculation. I based the answer on the information that the OP gave. It's hardly useful to answer a question assuming that the OP is lying.

Comment: No one is assuming that the OP is lying.  To not include all information about a particular schema is not tantamount to lying.  *You*, however, are playing fast and loose with the truth with that last comment of yours.

Comment: @Guildenstern: In what way am I "playing fast and loose the the truth"? What are you accusing me of, exactly?